# What is the maximum amount of health and stamina Dovahkiin can get (No mods)?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am trying to get a better idea as to who would win Dovahkiin or The Lone Wanderer. To do this I am looking into all the maxed out perks and health and stamina (**no magicka as it is unfair for The Lone Wanderer**) I want his health and stamina the same.

Answer (score 3):

Dallium's answer is correct if you allow legendary skills. Infinite health probably isn't the answer you want though.

Without legendary skills, the level cap is 81 (so 80 level ups). The dovahkiin starts with 100 in Magicka, Health, and Stamina and can put 10 in any of these on level up.

A Dovahkiin with 100 in all skills will have a total of 1100. Since you specified no magic, that's 100 magicka and 1000 total health and stamina.

**500 health, 500 stamina** seems reasonable for estimates, though going more health and less stamina is possible.

Comment: +1, though I point out that going for more stamina and less health is just as possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit, because there's no level cap. You can continue to reset your skills from 100 to 15, and keep gaining levels and stats.

Comment: Translation:  You are limited only by your tolerance for "The Grind".